# Duplicate fields on a 2-step form and insert in a mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So, i've got a 2-step form. On the first step user must fill their personal info which can be done once. 
 On the 2nd step they must fill the area they visited and add some information about it. Right now the visitor can submit the form once. 
What i wanna do is to add a button at the end of the second step which will allow users to duplicate all the fields of the 2nd step in case they visited more than 1 places that same day. 
You can see the form here: http://bit.ly/1BljbGU

 Afterwards if they visit 2 places and then submit the form, i want the first step information to get resubmitted for the both places in my database so they won't have to fill the first step again and again.

Here's the code of the first and the second step as well as the insert to the database file: http://bit.ly/1GfqaSK

Comment: So what's the problem? What's the question? Did you try to do it and ran into a problem?

Comment: Yes, this question is pretty broad.  You might have more luck dividing it up into a small number of questions.

Comment: I tried to add the button using this tutorial: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html but i can't get around the insertion of the information into the database.